# Cross domain, site collection migration

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-database, cross-domain, database-attach

We need to migration a site collection is running on SharePoint foundation 2013 server to another domain.

I m planing to take the backup of content database and restore it in new farm then attach it to Web application using  **Mount spcontent database** command.

Is this right approach or do I have to take another approach to accomplish this task !

Answer (score 4):

That's the right approach to take, but you'll need to do a couple of other things as well:

1. When you've restored the DB to the new SQL server, run EXEC sp_chagedbowner 'domain\user' to change the owner of the content database to the farm admin (also known as the database access account) for the new farm.
2. Ensure that the authentication mechanism of the web application that you are attaching the database to is the same as the source farm web application.
3. You'll need to perform a 'Move-SPUser' against each user account that used the source farm site collection to migrate the user account information to the new domain. See [Move-SPUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx) for details of this command.

Comment: thanks Andy, specially for move-spuser details.....  I ll be posting complete step once done with this task.